# Call Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST APIs using the web activity in an Azure Synapse pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-storage, pipeline, azure-synapse-analytics

How can I use the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API to rename a folder in an Azure Storage Account using the web activity in a Synapse pipeline?
The folders are in the same container, and I need to rename them by executing a pipeline.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? any errors/blockers?

Comment: I referred to this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1186452/how-to-rename-folders-in-adls-using-adf), but it lacks details about the process. When I try to implement it, I encounter numerous issues with the headers and body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename a folder in ADLS Gen 2 using REST API and web activity, follow the procedure below:

First, add the `storage blob data contributor` role to your Synapse workspace managed identity as follows:

Step 1: Go to the IAM of the ADLS account and click on "Add role assignment" as shown below:

[image]

Step 2: Search for the `storage Blob data contributor` role and select it, as shown below:

[image]

Step 3: Select the Managed identity, as shown below:

[image]

After successfully assigning the role, go to the Synapse workspace, create a pipeline with web activity, and configure the web activity as follows:

Mention the URL in the format below:

```
 https://<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<containerName>/<newNameOfFolder>
```

Select the `PUT` method and add `@toLower('')` dynamic content to the body. Select **System Assigned Managed Identity** as the authentication method with `https://storage.azure.com` resource. Add `x-ms-rename-source` as a header with the value `/<containerName>/<oldNameOfFolder>`, as shown below:

[image]

Debug the pipeline; it will run successfully and rename the folder. You can check the images below:

Before renaming:

[image]

After renaming:

[image]